# two points are close to eachother if there are a lot of open sets that contain both of them

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I started taking an introductory course on topology of the real numbers.

I am familiar with the ideas of open sets , closed sets , limit points , interior points ...

However , I have came across a particular definition of two points being close to eachother that goes as follows :

**Definition:**

We say two points are close to eachother if there are a lot of open sets that contain both of them.

Worded differently:

The closer two points are to each other , the more open sets  contain them at the same time.

**My Question:**

I'm having a hard time grasping this concept of points being close using open sets

How does it relate to the same idea of distance and how to visualise it ?

What is the intuition behind it ?

And if possible how can i more formally  write this  in terms of topological definitions ?

Comment: Where did you get that definition from? "a lot of open sets" is very imprecise. Is 10 a lot? What about 10000? The major distinction between topology and distance is that with distance we can precisely say what it means for two points to be close. With topology we cannot, "being close" is meaningless.

Comment: There are "a lot" of open sets that contain any two given points.

Comment: "We say two points are close to eachother if there are a lot of open sets that contain both of them.

Worded differently:

The closer two points are to each other , the more open sets contain them at the same time."

This is *not* a definition, as "a lot" is not defined. So I've downvoted your question. Who gave you this definition? Whoever did so is being imprecise.

Comment: I apologize for being so imprecise , but this is what got me just as confused . as i can have infintely many open sets contain those two points .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to view this is how separated are they by what open sets contain one but not the other. Your 'definition' of close, with how many open sets contain both,  can fail if the topology is trivial. In that case there is only one open set. By every conceivable notion of close, a point should be infinitely close to itself, but your description does not capture it. Closeness should probably prefer description by smaller open sets.

I think the better notion to understanding closeness in topology is separation axioms, See [separation axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom). Since distance defines a topology by the collection of balls, you can say two points $x,y$ are $\delta$-separated if $d(x,y)>\delta$. Or in a more topological language, there is no ball $B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}(z)$ containing both points.

That's at least my view on it.

Answer (score 0):

In a topological space we do not talk about closeness in the sense of distance. Distance is a concept defined in metric spaces, not in topological spaces. We talk about abstract closeness, something more related to similarity or likeness than to distance.

In a metric space, when somebody asks “how close are these two points?” you answer with a number: their distance. In a topological space, you answer with the list of properties that they share.

We identify sets with properties. Having such property means belonging to the (sub)set of all elements (of the topological space) that have that property. Then we can measure the proximity of two points by which properties (that we care about) they share.

The collection of open sets of a topological space represents the collection of properties that the points of the space may (or may not) have. For this collection to make sense, it has to meet the following requirements.

- There is one property (being a point of the space) that all points have. That is, the whole space is an open set.
- There is one property (not being a point of the space) that no point has. That is, the empty set is an open set.
- Given any two properties, having one and the other is also a valid property. That is, the intersection of open sets is an open set. This can be extended to the intersection of a finite number of open sets. And why not to the intersection of an infinite number of open sets? Because it would not be operative. How do we prove that an object has all the properties in an infinite list? Verifying one property after the other may take an infinite    amount of time. Or in other words, it may be a non computable    problem.
- Given any two properties, having one or the other is also a    valid property. That is, the union of open sets is an open set. In this case, the extension to an infinite union makes sense. To prove that an object has one of the properties of an infinite list we can just show the one that it has.

These are the axioms used to define a topological space by means of open sets.

I hope that this helps to see the logic behind that (very imprecise, I agree with others) definition of closeness in topological spaces cited in the question.

Comment: I'd like to thank you for the answer !  I've read some similar ones presenting the idea of finite time of computation for semi-decideable properties . In other words that open sets are sets which properties can be determined in finite time